# Pandas read_csv Bad lines - Seperator in strings with uneven quoting

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to read a bunch of .csv files from an FTP dump which I want to load into our SQL server. However, I am getting a lot of bad lines errors when trying to do so. I narrowed the problem down and it seems to be happening in lines where the string quotes are bad.

Example csv-data:

```text
"column before problem", "Random string "More String", final part of string", "column after problem"
```

The data is input like this as a kind of air quote - so real life data could look like:

"This person suffers from "Abnormal Appetite", which cause them to eat alot"

The code I am using:

```py
ch = pd.read_csv(file, 
                 chunksize=100000, 
                 low_memory=False, 
                 quotechar='"', 
                 encoding="iso-8859-1")
df = pd.concat(chunk)
```

I have tried to read both with and without the `quotechar` argument.

Edit 1: added picture of csv file
[Picture of part of one of the csv files that produces the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KV1aN.png)

Edit 2: added csv file in text, deleted the empty columns at the end

```text
"REDACTED","REDACTED","REDACTED","REDACTED","F",08/05/2014,"10:00:00","BB",30,"2050","REDACTED",0,0,"U",0,
"REDACTED","REDACTED","REDACTED","REDACTED","F",03/10/2014,"13:30:00","BB",30,"2050","Doesnt want BEH, only us, because she isnt "gameready", therefore just 1/2 hours",0,0,"U",0,
```

Edit 3: added the csv file in text WITH empty fields:

```text
klinik_id,firma_id,patientid,ds_cpr,ds_sex,ds_dato,ds_klokke,ds_behandl,ds_varighe,ds_status,ds_beskrivelse,ds_aktiv,ds_stamp,ds_atype,ds_forsink,bit1,bit2,bit3,bit4,bit5,bit6,bit7,bit8,bit9,bit10,bit11,bit12,bit13,bit14,bit15,bit16,bit17,bit18,bit19,bit20,bit21,bit22,bit23,bit24,bit25,bit26,bit27,bit28,bit29,bit30,bit31,bit32,bit33,bit34,bit35,bit36,bit37,bit38,bit39,bit40,bit41,bit42,bit43,bit44,bit45,bit46,bit47,bit48    
"REDACTED","REDACTED","REDACTED","REDACTED","F",08/05/2014,"10:00:00","BB",30,"2050","REDACTED",0,0,"U",0," ","J"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","J"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "
"REDACTED","REDACTED","REDACTED","REDACTED","F",03/10/2014,"13:30:00","BB",30,"2050","Doesnt want BEH, only us, because she isnt "gameready", therefore just 1/2 hours",0,0,"U",0," ","J"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," ","J"," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "
```

Edit 4: Sample dataframe info print with top 4 lines:

```text
Data columns (total 79 columns):
 #   Column          Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------          --------------  ----- 
 0   klinik_id       4 non-null      object
 1   firma_id        4 non-null      int64 
 2   patientid       4 non-null      int64 
 3   ds_cpr          4 non-null      int64 
 4   ds_sex          4 non-null      object
 5   ds_dato         4 non-null      object
 6   ds_klokke       4 non-null      object
 7   ds_behandl      4 non-null      object
 8   ds_varighe      4 non-null      int64 
 9   ds_status       4 non-null      int64 
 10  ds_beskrivelse  4 non-null      object
 11  ds_aktiv        4 non-null      int64 
 12  ds_stamp        4 non-null      int64 
 13  ds_atype        4 non-null      object
 14  ds_forsink      4 non-null      int64 
 15  bit1            4 non-null      object
 16  bit2            4 non-null      object
 17  bit3            4 non-null      object
 18  bit4            4 non-null      object
 19  bit5            4 non-null      object
 20  bit6            4 non-null      object
 21  bit7            4 non-null      object
 22  bit8            4 non-null      object
 23  bit9            4 non-null      object
 24  bit10           4 non-null      object
 25  bit11           4 non-null      object
 26  bit12           4 non-null      object
 27  bit13           4 non-null      object
 28  bit14           4 non-null      object
 29  bit15           4 non-null      object
 30  bit16           4 non-null      object
 31  bit17           4 non-null      object
 32  bit18           4 non-null      object
 33  bit19           4 non-null      object
 34  bit20           4 non-null      object
 35  bit21           4 non-null      object
 36  bit22           4 non-null      object
 37  bit23           4 non-null      object
 38  bit24           4 non-null      object
 39  bit25           4 non-null      object
 40  bit26           4 non-null      object
 41  bit27           4 non-null      object
 42  bit28           4 non-null      object
 43  bit29           4 non-null      object
 44  bit30           4 non-null      object
 45  bit31           4 non-null      object
 46  bit32           4 non-null      object
 47  bit33           4 non-null      object
 48  bit34           4 non-null      object
 49  bit35           4 non-null      object
 50  bit36           4 non-null      object
 51  bit37           4 non-null      object
 52  bit38           4 non-null      object
 53  bit39           4 non-null      object
 54  bit40           4 non-null      object
 55  bit41           4 non-null      object
 56  bit42           4 non-null      object
 57  bit43           4 non-null      object
 58  bit44           4 non-null      object
 59  bit45           4 non-null      object
 60  bit46           4 non-null      object
 61  bit47           4 non-null      object
 62  bit48           4 non-null      object
 63  bit49           4 non-null      object
 64  bit50           4 non-null      object
 65  bit51           4 non-null      object
 66  bit52           4 non-null      object
 67  bit53           4 non-null      object
 68  bit54           4 non-null      object
 69  bit55           4 non-null      object
 70  bit56           4 non-null      object
 71  bit57           4 non-null      object
 72  bit58           4 non-null      object
 73  bit59           4 non-null      object
 74  bit60           4 non-null      object
 75  bit61           4 non-null      object
 76  bit62           4 non-null      object
 77  bit63           4 non-null      object
 78  bit64           4 non-null      object
dtypes: int64(8), object(71)
```

Comment: Could you share what the .csv looks like? Please reduce it to the minimum, so that the problem still can be reproduced.

Comment: @normanius Added a picture in the question, let me know if you need more.

Comment: I think the bigger problem is that the quoted string contains a commas!

Comment: When dumping data, use a different column separator (like `;`). Then call `pd.read_csv(..., sep=";")`.

Comment: The CSV "standard" is hopelessly fuzzy around the edges. However, I'd say that input file is simply not correct — the quotation marks inside a quoted field need to be doubled. See for example section 2.7 of [RFC 4180](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180#section-2). If possible, fix the problem upstream.

Comment: You'd have to write your own parser for this as the input data does not comply with CSV standards

Comment: Could you add that CSV example to your question in text format, we could then copy/paste it

Comment: @normanius unfortunately I don't control the data dump, an external supplier does and they are very slow to implement..

Comment: @TurePålsson I agree, but we do not control the upstream.

Comment: If you only have one badly quoted field, then the correct (empty) fields at the end can be used to help extract (can you add back the empty fields into the question?)

Comment: @DarkKnight would you use the built in csv library for that or go completely from scratch?

Comment: Are you sure the header is correct? Does it normally go up to `bit64` ?

Comment: @MartinEvans Yeah i'm positive. I added a print out of the shape of the frame in Edit 4 and am able to reproduce the error when using a known error line in combination with a normal line and normal headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is only one badly formatted field, one approach would be to accept all fields up to it, and backwards from the end all correct fields and then join all remaining fields together.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

data = []

with open('input.csv') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    columns = next(csv_input) + [f'bit{n}' for n in range(49, 65)]
    
    for row in csv_input:
        comment = ''.join(row[10:-68]).replace('"', '')
        data.append([*row[:10], comment, *row[-68:]])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
print(df)
```

For your example 3 line CSV, this would display:

```
  klinik_id  firma_id patientid    ds_cpr ds_sex     ds_dato ds_klokke ds_behandl ds_varighe ds_status                                                                 ds_beskrivelse ds_aktiv ds_stamp ds_atype ds_forsink bit1 bit2 bit3 bit4 bit5 bit6 bit7 bit8 bit9 bit10 bit11 bit12 bit13 bit14 bit15 bit16 bit17 bit18 bit19 bit20 bit21 bit22 bit23 bit24 bit25 bit26 bit27 bit28 bit29 bit30 bit31 bit32 bit33 bit34 bit35 bit36 bit37 bit38 bit39 bit40 bit41 bit42 bit43 bit44 bit45 bit46 bit47 bit48     bit49 bit50 bit51 bit52 bit53 bit54 bit55 bit56 bit57 bit58 bit59 bit60 bit61 bit62 bit63 bit64
0  REDACTED  REDACTED  REDACTED  REDACTED      F  08/05/2014  10:00:00         BB         30      2050                                                                       REDACTED        0        0        U          0         J                                                    J                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
1  REDACTED  REDACTED  REDACTED  REDACTED      F  03/10/2014  13:30:00         BB         30      2050  Doesnt want BEH, only us, because she isnt gameready therefore just 1/2 hours        0        0        U          0         J                                                    J
```

It depends how exact it needs to be. This approach would lose the extra quotes in the comment field.

Note: There appears to be 79 columns in the data but the header in the example only shows 63? The code optionally adds the missing `bit49` to `bit64` columns (remove if not needed)

Comment: This works. All I needed to alter was passing encoding="iso-8859-1" to the open statement and it ran every file without issues.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Option quotechar results in ignoring delimiter in quoted section so it goes to singe column. If your file is correctly delimited just read it and replace quote:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file).replace('"','',regex=True)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not correctly quoted. Removing " with a regex would mean still having the bad line error as the expected # of cols would be still be less than the "actual" number due to the comma.

Comment: Comma inside a quoted value isn’t a problem, what is a problem is that there are further “ inside the value - these should have been written as doubled “” to work correctly

Answer (score 0):

This is rather cumbersome but as far as I can tell, it does solve the problem. There may be cleaner/tidier ways to do this and I've no doubt the SO pedants will take great delight in pointing that out to me but here goes anyway:-

```
import pandas as pd
import io

DQ = '"'
SQ = "'"
COMMA = ','


def fixCol(line, s, e=None):
    nl = line[s:e].strip() if e else line[s:].strip()
    if nl[0:1] == DQ and nl.count(DQ) == 4:
        return DQ + nl[1:].replace(DQ, SQ, 2)
    return nl


with open('test.csv') as csv:
    F = []
    for k, line in enumerate(csv.readlines()):
        if k == 0:
            F.append(line) # headers
            continue
        T = []
        s = q = 0
        for i in range(len(line)):
            if q % 2 == 0 and line[i] == COMMA:
                T.append(fixCol(line, s, i))
                s = i + 1
                q = 0
            else:
                if line[i] == DQ:
                    q += 1
        if s < len(line):
            T.append(fixCol(line, s))
        F.append(','.join(T))

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('\n'.join(F)))
print(df)
```